# Using an if statement to check if a record doesn't exist not working in sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to check if a record doesn't exist in an other table. It must do an insert and perform an update only on that entry and not on any of the existing items in that table.
This is what I tried:

```
IF NOT exists (SELECT *
                    FROM dbo.Log  s inner join #results r on s.Number = r.Number)
   BEGIN
       insert into  //if it doesn't exist enter the row dbo.Log(Number,FirstName,LastName,Mobile,MessageContent,MessageStatus)
       select Number
             ,FirstName
             ,LastName
             ,MobileNumber
             ,MessageContent
             ,MessageStatus
       from #results r
 update r //then only update that row that was inserted
    set TextNumb = v.TextNumber
    from 
    (select r.*, row_number() over (order by newid()) as seqnum
      from [dbo].[Log] r where MessageStatus=0
     ) r join
     (select v.*, row_number() over (order by newid()) as seqnum
      from dbo.TextNUMBERS v
      where Flag=0
     ) v
     on r.seqnum = v.seqnum;
     update dbo.TextNUMBERS
            set flag =1
     from  [dbo].[Log] re 
 where re.TextNumb=dbo.TextNumbers.TextNumber
 END
```

So in the above I tried that if the record doesn't exist then insert and update only that record, but it's not working, it's only inserting the first time when I run the query with no values in the other table but if I run the query the second time it doesn't insert any new record that comes in after that.

I also tried:

```
insert into 
    dbo.Log(Number,FirstName,LastName,Mobile,MessageContent,MessageStatus)
           select Number
                 ,FirstName
                 ,LastName
                 ,MobileNumber
                 ,MessageContent
                 ,MessageStatus
           from #results r
where not exists (select 1
from dbo.log s
where s.Number=r.Number)
```

The above works in checking if the record doesn't exist and it does the insert but the problem with this is that I can't update only the record that was inserted, because it ends up updating everything in the log table.

So how do I get my if statement to work? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: 1. If the records to be inserted / updated are stored in `#results`,  join to `#results` in your update statements to only update the relevant records. 2. I think you are missing an `ELSE` in your `IF` statement but I am not sure. The queries provided are a bit of a mess.

Comment: but how would i know which record needs to be updated in #results because i need to check if it exists in the log table first

Comment: Hint:  `MERGE` will do both at once.